# How to databind to a property of an object within an object (Nested object's property)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am having issues with databinding to a custom view that I've created in Xamarin. I'm new to Xamarin but have a few years programming experience. I am pulling data from a digital access management API, and deserializing it into an object, "Item".

```
public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("external_id")]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_update_date")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thumbnails")]
    public Dictionary<string, Thumbnail> Thumbnails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_links")]
    public Links Links { get; set; }

}
```

I've omitted some of the unnecessary fields that im not using for simplicity.

Within the properties of that Item class, is a dictionary`<string, Thumbnail> Thumbnails`

The "Thumbnail" class looks like this:

```
public partial class Thumbnail
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("valid_until")]
    public DateTimeOffset ValidUntil { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is my issue: In the custom view that I've set up (in order to display some info about the item in a list view, I've inherited from ViewCell), I want to databind to the Thumbnails["Key"].Url value for each item. For now, I'm just trying to display the url to test that its working, eventually I'll actually load the photo.

Here is the custom view I've made:

```
public class AssetCell : ViewCell
{
    public AssetCell()
    {
        var urlLabel = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
        };
        urlLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Thumbnails[125px].Url"));

        //var titleLabel = new Label
        //{
        //    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
        //    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
        //};
        //titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Filename"));

        var updatedDateLabel = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)),
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
        };
        updatedDateLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("LastUpdateDate", stringFormat: "{0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}"));

        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { urlLabel, updatedDateLabel },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 10, 0)
        };

    }
}
```

Binding to direct properties of the Item class (such as the commented out titleLabel, and updatedDateLabel) work as expected, but I cannot access the properties of the Thumbnails dictionary (and beyond that, the URI Url property of a Thumbnail object) that are part of the overall Item object.

I have tried to research this for a while and have come up with no results. Is there a way to set the binding to a nested object's property? Is this the correct way of going about it? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure "125px" is a valid key?

Comment: @Jason Yes, when I try printing out the url I'm looking for on one of the Item objects, I can access that url like this: item.Thumbnails["125px"].Url and it prints no problem. I'm not sure why it won't work in the custom view though. The custom view is simply looking for those properties since there is no actual 'Item' object that gets passed in (as far as I understand, only a few days into learning Xamarin)

Comment: why are you setting the Label's BindingContext = ""?  Does it work if you comment that out?

Comment: @Jason Sorry, I forgot to take that out when I posted, I was just playing around with it to try to make it work/learn. I've taken it out of my code and the binding still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked with databinding in XAML, but for databinding for for nested objects should just work for the most part.

However, trying to access dictionary by the  key might be causing issues with databinding.

Also, Xamarin seems to not like types that aren't implicitly convertible when data binding (eg: your label text property binding should be a string not Uri object)

I suggest writing a converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Where value is your dictionary, and you can feed the key through converter parameter.

You'd then just return the uri string by using value[param], assuming you cast things from object correctly.

```
public class DictionaryToStringConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    // cast object to dictionary
    Dictionary<string, Thumbnail> thumbnails = value as Dictionary<string, Thumbnail>;
    // cast parameter to dictionary key 
    String key = parameter as string;

    // retrieve value from dictionary
    Uri uri = thumbnails[key].Url;

    // returning string because label's text property is string
    return uri.AbsoluteUri;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented");
  }
}
```

I'd be interested to know if there are better solutions though.